# Include path relative to Makefile regarding assembler (GAS) files

Tags: makefile, include, include-path

Let's say I've got the following project structure:

```
<ASM_Project>/
├── <src>/
│   └── <boot>/
│       ├── boot.s
│       └── functions.s
└── Makefile
```

`boot.s`:

```
_start:
  jmp testing

.include "src/boot/functions.s"

testing:
```

`Makefile`:

```
src/boot/boot.o: src/boot/boot.s src/boot/functions.s
    as -o $@ $<
```

`boot.s` and `functions.s` are in the same folder and yet `.include "functions"` doesn't seem to work in this case:

```
Ernie@Sanderson:~/ASM_Project$ make
as -o src/boot/boot.o src/boot/boot.s
src/boot/boot.s: Assembler messages:
src/boot/boot.s:11: Error: can't open functions.s for reading: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:23: src/boot/boot.o] Error 1
```

Is there a way to pull it off though?

Comment: Are you sure the `.include` directive doesn't expect a path relative to the *current* file?  In which case it would be `.include "functions.s"` .

Comment: I'd have thought so, but if it's `include "functions"` I get `Error: can't open functions.s for reading: No such file or directory`

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you invoke `make` as well as any error message(s).

Comment: The `.include "src/boot/functions.s"` directive works fine for me (using clang/LLVM assembler 10.0.0).

Comment: `.include "src/boot/functions.s"` does work fine indeed, it's `.include "functions"` that doesn't, even though `boot.s` and `functions.s` are in the same folder, hence the question about the possibility of not having to change every `.include` path inside `boot.s` to `src/boot/`.

Comment: Sorry I was confused by the wording.  Isn't it simply a case of adding `-Isrc/boot` to the assembler command in the makefile?